# validating a file upload while submitting the form in angular js

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, file-upload

I need to validate my file upload and display error message if user clicks on submit without uploading any file.My code is

```
<div class=" form-label form-label-responsive col-sm-4 text-right" ><span>Upload a file</span></div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6" ng-class="{{(_DominoForm['%%File.ca257e9d000513c5.c758deaebd88bc7fca257ea40005f6fe.$Body.0.70'].$invalid)? 'has-error' : 'has-success'}}">


    <input class= "form-control form-input" data-file id="%%File.ca257e9d000513c5.c758deaebd88bc7fca257ea40005f6fe.$Body.0.70" name="%%File.ca257e9d000513c5.c758deaebd88bc7fca257ea40005f6fe.$Body.0.70" ng-model="my_file_model" type="file" 
    required="true">


    <p ng-show="_DominoForm['%%File.ca257e9d000513c5.c758deaebd88bc7fca257ea40005f6fe.$Body.0.70'].$error.required  ">

    <span class="icon icon-size-sm icon-alert" aria-labelledby="error-text"></span>

    <span class="ng-binding"> Please select a file </span>

  </p>
```

My form name is _DominoForm. I dont undersand what am i doing wrong.
No error is displayed when I click on submit.
Any  help would be appreciated.